# SVG - how to define transformation on two distinct elements

Tags: javascript, svg, transformation

I have the following svg:

```
<svg 
    width="1750" 
    height="1125" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g>
        <g id="svg_4">
        <g id="imgG_4">
        <image 
            transform="rotate(35.3608 608.333 503.301)" 
            xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" 
            id="img_4" 
            height="188.79927" 
            width="188.79927" 
            y="408.90001" 
            x="706.21582"/>
       </g>
       <rect 
           transform="rotate(35.3608 783.333 667.587)" 
           id="border_4" 
           height="264.31644" 
           width="360.92146" 
           y="535.42838" 
           x="602.87256" 
           fill-opacity="0" 
           stroke-width="5" 
           stroke="#000000" 
           fill="#000000"/>
       </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

I'd like to change the angle of the both the rect and image. I cannot however, figure out how to adjust the image such that its spacing within the rect is consistent as i rotate the rect.

E.g.  After rotating both the rect and the image the image has the same amount of whitespace above and to the left as it did prior to rotation of both elements.

I cannot put the rotation on the container groups due to other technical restraints.

I'd like to end up with something like:

```
<svg
    width="1750"
    height="1125"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g>
        <g
            id="svg_4">
            <g
                id="imgG_4">
                <image
                    transform="rotate(70.3608 608.333 503.301)"
                    xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"
                    id="img_4"
                    height="188.79927"
                    width="188.79927"
                    y="408.90001"
                    x="706.21582"
                    />
            </g>
            <rect
                transform="rotate(70.3608 783.333 667.587)"
                id="border_4"
                height="264.31644"
                width="360.92146"
                y="535.42838"
                x="602.87256"
                fill-opacity="0"
                stroke-width="5"
                stroke="#000000"
                fill="#000000"
                />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The caveat is that the x,y values have to change on the image in order to get the layout correct and I have know idea how to calculate them.

Any idea on how I would go about this?   I will be using javascript to do the math involved...

Plnkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lMqkhzk2vQ326sCTbFe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to rotate both elements around the same rotation point as the rectangle (ie. 783.333,667.587), then all you need to is apply the additional rotation to the front of both element transforms.  So:

```
<image transform="rotate(90 783.333 667.587) rotate(70.3608 608.333 503.301)"
<rect  transform="rotate(90 783.333 667.587) rotate(70.3608 783.333 667.587)"
```

would rotate both elements an additional 90deg round the above centre of rotation.

However you said you want to do the maths yourself in Javascript.  So to get you started, it might help to know that the transform:

```
rotate(r x y)
```

is equivalent to:

```
translate(x y) rotate(r) translate(-x -y)
```

Comment: That does it!  Thank you.